# devoting just some certain cpu's for a notebook

Tags: notebooks

how can we devote certain CPU series to one notebook.

For example, I have run a program on a notebook the result of performance is

[image]

but I want to have two cpu's completely busy and two others un-busy.

[image]

We can go to preference->Parallel but this option cannot work for my aim.

Comment: A notebook: no.  A kernel process: maybe. You can assign different kernels to different notebooks. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479458/is-there-a-way-to-lock-a-process-to-a-cpu) the keyword is "CPU affinity".  But I'm not sure this qualifies as a Mathematica question as the key is getting a process (any process, whether it's a Mathematica kernel or something else) to be locked to a certain CPU.  Note that the Mathematica kernel uses multiple CPU (cores) for certain operations, and I'm not sure if that will be a problem...

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/change-the-processor-affinity-setting-in-windows-7-to-gain-a-performance-edge/